# How to do partials with haml in metalsmith-layouts

Tags: haml, metalsmith

How can I use partials with haml in metalsmith-layouts?

The docs lists `{{> nested/footer }}` as a way to use partials in handlebars but I can't work out an equivalent for haml.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `consolidate.js` doesn't implement the `partials` option for all it's supported templating languages (which is what metalsmith-layouts and in-place use when you use the `partials` option).

If you check the [consolidate.js source](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/lib/consolidate.js#L584) for haml you can see that it doesn't use the `partials` object when rendering haml. The `locals` option *is* parsed however, so you could see if you can use that.

Metalsmith-layouts and in-place will pass on any options they don't recognise to consolidate, so passing a `locals` option would be the way to go.